# javascript closure with callback exit

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm sure i'm missing something obvious since its been a while in javascript world but my searches have yielded nothing, only blog and tutor on closure basics. So, I have a function that takes a callback, which executes another function that also takes a callback, which never finishes execution and just returns. e.g.

```
function first(y,z,callback){}
function second(x,y,callback){}
```

so on-click event.

```
first(1,2,function(){
    second(1,2,function(){ 
      //do something....
    })//exits after exec.
    alert('this never get fired');
})
```

How do i prevent the second function's callback from exiting and allow execution of the rest of the code in the block? any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: There is probably an error somewhere that you're missing. What do you see in the console?

Comment: What you've shown us is a syntax error (`function(){}` is not a valid parameter name). Please show us your actual code of `first` and `second` functions.

Comment: Your declaration of `first()` and `second()` is syntactic nonsense. A formal parameter cannot be a function declaration. Aside from that, `first()` never executes the call-back argument, so there's no surprise that the alert never fires. perhaps you can show us your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "function first(y,z,function(){})" should be changed to accept a function argument that you can call back/execute in the function body, like so:

```
function first(y,z,fn){fn();}
function second(x,y,fn){fn();}
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    first(1,2,function(){
        second(1,2,function(){ 
          //do something....
        })//exits after exec.
        alert('this never get fired');
    });
});
```

Comment: As written, of course, `first` and `second` are identical functions, so one could get by with only one of them. Presumably OP's actual use case requires two separate functions.

Comment: sorry for the mistype. are there any cases where after the callback from the second function completes that it would just exit?